# vim syntax highlight

Tags: syntax-highlighting, syntax

Syntax highlighting just stopped working on my mac (v 10.14.6). I've been trying to get it back over the past 2 days with no success. I have neovim (v 0.3.8) and when I use `:syntax`, the command line says:

```
No Syntax items defined for this buffer.
```

Also, I am using iterm2.

Below is a snippet of my `init.vim` file:

```
:filetype plugin indent on  
:syntax on
set background=dark
colorscheme base16-snazzy
set termguicolors
```

Comment: What does `:set ft?` say? What does `:filetype` say? Please update the question with the results...

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! As filbranden says, it’s pretty hard for us to debug exactly what’s going on here. Does that snippet work if its the only content of your init.vim?

Comment: See also https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604, and feel free to [edit] your Q

Comment: The result from :filetype is filetype detection:ON  plugin:ON  indent:ON, and the result from :set ft? is filetype=

Comment: The second part (`filetype=`) is likely part of the problem... You normally need a filetype set to have syntax highlighting. What kind of file are you editing, when you're having problem with syntax? What kind of filename pattern/extension on the file?